# Oracle PL/SQL select only the unique ones and one random record

Tags: distinct

I want to make the following select on Oracle PL/SQL:

I have two columns ServedIMSI, Servicekey. There are many servicekey dublicates, so I want to select only the unique ones and one random record for ServedIMSI that matches on the number of the servicekey . Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace `t1` with your table's real name):

```
select 
distinct(ServedIMSI) ServedIMSI, 
(select Servicekey from t1 a 
  where a.ServedIMSI = t.ServedIMSI and rownum=1) Servicekey
from t1 t
```

You can find a running example [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bcfae/4)

Comment: I found a sollution 

SELECT ServiceKey, min(ServedIMSI) FROM <>
GROUP BY ServiceKey 

Sorry and thank You